# Quero gravar as informações em um .txt em c++

Tags: c++

O problema aqui é que ele cria o arquivo 'test.txt' porem quando chega na hora de gravar no arquivo ele não faz nada...
eu ja vi a permissão do arquivo e esta ok...
não entendi alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero; 
    string name; 
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("c:\\x\\test.txt");
    if (! outFile) 
    {
        cout << "erro test.txt" << endl; 
        abort(); 
    } 

    cout << "Name: \n" 
        << "Fim de arquivo (Ctrl-Z) termina a entrada de dados\n\n? "; 
    while(cin >> numero >> name){ 
        outFile << numero << " " << name<< '\n'; // << Chega aqui ele não faz nada
        cout << "? "; 
    } 
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No cout tenta assim || outFile << (numero) << " " << (name)<< "\n"; ||

Comment: Provavelmente o SO não esta fazendo o flush para o arquivo. Troque `'\n'` por `endl` e verifique se resolve.

Comment: da ero quando tento (outFile << (numero) << " " << (name)<< "\n";)

Comment: edita a pergunta e posta o erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que o sistema operacional não esta realizando o flush dos dados para o arquivo devido ao CTRL+Z.

Para corrigir este problema, basta substituir o `'\n'` por `endl`:

```
outFile << numero << " " << name << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << input;
    out.close();
    return 0;
}

-------------------------------------------

std::ofstream file;
file.open("filename");
std::string my_string = "Oi qual o seu nome?\n";
file << my_string;
file.close();
```